# java -xbootclass path is no longer a supported option

Tags: java, linux, jar, runtime-error

I upgrade the linux system and java package was also upgraded. I was running a jar file with command `java -Xbootclasspath/p:b.jar -jar c.jar` and now this error occurs:

> -Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option.
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: You will have to refer to the developer. Off topic.

Comment: how man it was working before upgrade its problem in java interpreter ! i think

Comment: It's a problem caused by the upgrade, obviously, and you will have to refer to the developer to get it resolved, as I said.

Comment: iam talking about system upgrade and upgrading java libs and version not the program it self !

Answer (score 8):

JAVA 11 doesn't support `-Xbootclasspath/p:`, so your command should be changed from `/p:` to `/a:`.

Before:

```
java -noverify -Xbootclasspath/p:
```

After:

```
java -noverify -Xbootclasspath/a:
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [Java 9 Release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html):

> The boot class path has been mostly removed in this release. The java `-Xbootclasspath` and `-Xbootclasspath/p` options have been removed. The javac `-bootclaspath` option can only be used when compiling to JDK 8 or older. The system property `sun.boot.class.path` has been removed. Deployments that rely on overriding platform classes for testing purposes with `-Xbootclasspath/p` will need to changed to use the `--patch-module` option that is documented in [JEP 261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261). The `-Xbootclasspath/a` option is unchanged.

Comment: could you tell me the full command to do the same job as above !

Answer (score 3):

Call the Java interpreter in JDKv8 (Found at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin`).

After the upgrade, the Java binary was symlink'ed to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` and I could execute it successfully.

Comment: This is not a good solution.  Public (free) updates for Java 8 are due to stop in Jan 2019.  You should figure out how to make the JAR work with Java 9 / 10.   Talk to the supplier of the app you are trying to run.